# JavaScript Regular Expression - Accept only two words with no special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying this below pattern in http://regex101.com/#javascript

Pattern: `[a-zA-Z]+\s{1}[a-zA-Z]+`

String: `'Testing Only two characters'`

http://regex101.com/r/gT0uX9 highlights only first two words of the string but when I try it in a fiddle, it says true. What is the problem? Am I doing something wrong?

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7KMZ/)**

Comment: Use [`.match()`](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/string/match)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `.test()` checks whether the regex matches or not. In your case it is matching correctly and hence true

What the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) says:

> **Use test() whenever you want to know whether a pattern is *found* in a
>   string (similar to the String.search method);** for more information
>   (but slower execution) use the exec method (similar to the
>   String.match method). As with exec (or in combination with it), test
>   called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance
>   will advance past the previous match.

(*emphasis mine*)
You can use anchors `^` and `$` if you want only two words.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+\s{1}[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Comment: Is there any way that it should return 'true' only when it has two words?

Comment: @Amit That was me. Your answer missed the point. The real answer was the bit I said, which I see you've now plagiarised, or at best added as an afterthought.

Answer (score 2):

It returns `true` because your string *contains* a string of two words. If you want to check whether the string *is* a string of two words, use the anchors `^` and `$` for start-of-string and end-of-string:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+\s{1}[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Comment: -1 from me. For telling that I plagiarized your content. OP asked what was the problem in his code. And I was right in answering to that. And I added the anchors after OP asked if it was possible.(You can check the comment of OP in my answer).

Comment: I admit I have no proof that you didn't think of it independently, and in fact I've already changed my comment. (I believe I wrote it first though.) OP's problem was that they wanted to return `false` for strings longer than two words. This was reasonably clear from the original question. Your answer was to use `.exec` instead of `.test`. When I ran the fiddle with `.exec` I got `["Testing Only"]` as output - not what OP wanted.

Comment: Now, when did I say to use `exec`?

Comment: That was just the doc, which I took from MDN

Comment: If you weren't advising OP to do what the doc said, why did you quote it? And what exactly were you offering in the way of concrete suggestion, in the early versions of your answer which didn't mention the `^` and `$` anchors?

Comment: `Am I doing something wrong?` was OP's question and not, `"How should I make it right"`. And I quoted that because it was from MDN and was not mine.

Comment: You missed part of the quote: "What is the problem?" OP clearly thought something was wrong; the other question was rhetorical. But contrary to what I said before, it's not very clear what they wanted. Perhaps `.exec` was what they were looking for. I guess the real answer is that they should use either `^$` or `.exec`, depending on what they were after.